# Getting this error when trying to use csv files for selenium : "The constructor FileReader(String) is undefined"

Tags: java, csv, selenium

I am trying to read csv files for my login test case in selenium, I have done this part in the fast (i.e: Code worked for fetching data from csv), But for this code some how I am not able to get what is wrong. Please help me in solving this one..I a writing this code in the Base file, and that method I will be calling in some other file.

**Below is one code file, where that Error is displayed.**

> Note: I have made the line where the error "The constructor CSVReader(FileReader) is undefined" is displayed

```
package com.gptoday.com.gptoday.testcases;

import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxProfile;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.internal.ProfilesIni;
import org.testng.annotations.AfterMethod;
import org.testng.annotations.BeforeMethod;
import com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.host.file.FileReader;
import java.io.Reader;
import com.opencsv.CSVReader;

public class Base {
    public WebDriver driver;

    @BeforeMethod
    public void BaseSetup(){
        ProfilesIni prof = new ProfilesIni();
        FirefoxProfile ffProfile= prof.getProfile ("vishvesh");
        ffProfile.setAcceptUntrustedCertificates(true);
        ffProfile.setAssumeUntrustedCertificateIssuer(false);

        String BaseUrl = "https://www.gptoday.com";
        System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver", "G:/Workplace/AutomationSetupFiles/Geckdriver/geckodriver.exe"); 
        driver = new FirefoxDriver (ffProfile);
        driver.get(BaseUrl);
    }

    @AfterMethod
    public void afterTest() {
        System.out.println("Success");
    }

    public void CheckCurrentURL(WebDriver driver){
        String actual_url;
        actual_url=driver.getCurrentUrl();   
    }

    public void csv(){
        String csvpath = "G:/Workplace/Test Automation Project";
        CSVReader reader = **new CSVReader(new FileReader(csvpath))**;
        String[] cell=new String[1000];

        while ((cell = reader.readNext())!=null)
        {
            System.out.println("After while loop");
            System.out.println("After for loop");
            String name = cell[0];
            System.out.println("name displayed = "+name );
            String email = cell[1];
            System.out.println("email displayed ="+email );
            String message = cell[2];
            System.out.println("message displayed="+message);

            //driver.findElement(username).sendKeys(name);
            //driver.findElement(password).sendKeys(email);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: your import is messed up, you used `import com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.host.file.FileReader;` instead of `import java.io.FileReader;`

Comment: Yeah I messed it up with the imports (
I imported "import java.io.FileReader;" , The Errors seems to have gone..Thanks for the help..) @japu_D_Cret

Answer (score 0):

import "java.io.FileReader" and the error should go.